# pandas and tuple check

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                   index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
```

where `num_legs`, `num_wings` and `num_specimen_seen` are columns.

Now, I've tuple like `('num_wings', 'num_legs')` and wanted to check are there values are df columns? if yes then return true else false.

`('num_wings', 'num_legs')` -> this will return true 
`('abc', 'num_legs')` -> false

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get_indexer` here.

---

```
idxr = df.columns.get_indexer(tup)
all(idxr>-1)
```

***Performance***

```
cols = pd.Index(np.arange(10_000))
tup = tuple(np.arange(10_001))

%timeit all(cols.get_indexer(tup)>-1)
3.86 ms ± 87.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit all(e in cols for e in tup)
5.96 ms ± 69.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to check if `all` elements of the tuple are contained in `df.columns`:

```py
df = ...

def check(tup):
    return all((e in df.columns) for e in tup)
```

---

#### Performance comparison

@user3483203 proposed an alternative, quite succinct, solution using `get_indexer`, so I performed a `timeit` comparison of both our solutions.

```py
import random
import string
import pandas as pd

def rnd_str(l):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(l))

unique_strings = set(rnd_str(3) for _ in range(20000))
cols = pd.Index(unique_strings)

tup = tuple(rnd_str(3) for _ in range(5000))

%timeit all(cols.get_indexer(tup)>-1)
# 714 µs ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit all(e in cols for e in tup)
# 639 ns ± 0.988 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

###

tup = tuple(rnd_str(3) for _ in range(10000))

%timeit all(cols.get_indexer(tup)>-1)
# 1.29 ms ± 29.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit all(e in cols for e in tup)
# 1.23 µs ± 20.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Turns out the solution proposed in this post is significantly faster. The key advantage of this approach is that the `all()` functions exits early as soon as any element of the tuple that's not in `df.columns` has been spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Y can't u iterate over each of the value in the tuple & check for them individually, if they are present in the dataframe.

```
>>> def check_presence(tuple):
...     for x in tuple:
...             if x not in df.columns:
...                     return False
...             return True

check_presence(('num_wings', 'num_legs')) # returns True
check_presence(('abc', 'num_legs')) # returns False
```